# Displaying timers in order of there time remaining

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a mainwindow with 4 instances of a factory. The factories have a time remaining to know when they finish. The factories got a method that gets there remaining time. I am calling the methods for all 4 instances in my main class, so i get 4 doubles that contain the seconds that are left on each factory.

Now, I want to display the order of when the factories finish.
Like:

1st - Factory 3

2nd - Factory 1

3rd - Factory 2

4th - Factory 4

I have got 4 labels for each position. How can I calculate which factory is going to finish first, second etc.. And place them in the right label?

All I can think of is writing a complicated if-statement.

I have tried to make a list and order them by value, but that way I don't know which factory belongs to the certain value.

Factory class:

```
 public double getRemaining()
    {
        seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(lblRemaining1.Content.ToString()).TotalSeconds;

        return seconds;
    }
```

Main class:

```
        public void calculateOrder()
    {
        remaining1 = Factory1.getRemaining();
        remaining2 = Factory2.getRemaining();
        remaining3 = Factory3.getRemaining();
        remaining4 = Factory4.getRemaining();


    }
```

Comment: Your `Factory::getRemaining()` doesn't even make sense when all 4 of them returns the same TotalSeconds of `lblRemaining1`.

Comment: They are all started at a different time and have a different amount of runtime, since they are instances they all got the same label. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var factories = new Factory[] { Factory1, Factory2, Factory3, Factory4 }
    .OrderBy(x => x.getRemaining()) // or, you can use OrderByDescending 
    .ToArray();

remaining1 = factories[0].getRemaining();
remaining2 = factories[1].getRemaining();
remaining3 = factories[2].getRemaining();
remaining4 = factories[3].getRemaining();
```

Comment: Yup, thats it. Thanks bro.